# Decision nodes and chance nodes definition in decision tree

Tags: decision-tree

Could someone please provide a definition of decision nodes, change nodes and end nodes.

I have view the decision tree interpretation on wikipedia and haven't found the clear definition about the three tree nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it is like this:

- **Decision Nodes**:
  The node where a there is a requirement set that determines the outcome: ex:Profit>50k.
- **Chance Node**:
  A node were there isn't a set requirement to determine where to go in the split but something that just has a probability of happening or not Ex: 50% chance of success or failure of a business.
- **End Nodes**:
  The end of a split, so something feeds into this but nothing comes out of it. Usually some result. Ex: Business is sucessful.

Answer (score 0):

DECISION NODE: These are variable's included on an influence diagrams or decision tree, they are points where decisions would have to be made, they are usually depicted by square or rectangle. by Master E. Felix.